$n$ students sit around a table ($n\geq 5$). By changing seats, the two students next to each student are different. Does this changing plan exist?
There are $n$ students sitting around the table. Through changing seats between two students, can we accomplish that two students next to each student are different from the initial situation?
This is a graph theory exercise from my textbook after learning some basic knowledge about the Hamiltonian graph.
I think we may need to discuss on two cases: $n$ is even or odd.
First of all, we need to model this question into a graph.  Vertexes represent students. Edges represent one student is next to another student in the initial situation.
And maybe we need to find a function $f: V\rightarrow V$ (where, e.g., $f(1) = 2$ means exchanging/swapping vertex 1's and 2's positions) which makes a Hamiltonian cycle into a empty graph whose number of edges is zero.
Is there such a function whether n is odd or even? I can't solve it by myself.

The 'neigbors' of both students being swapped must be four distinct people. This implies there need to be at least two people sitting between the two in each direction. As a result, $n$ must be at least $6$.
For $n=5$ it's not possible – each two students either are neigbors, so they still will be sitting next to one another after the swap, ot they have a common neighbor, who will still be their common neighbor after the swap.
Edit
One can rearrange five people around a table so that each of them will get two new neighbors. However, this can't be done by swapping just two of them, four of the five would need to move. Compare a pentagram, a five-pointed star and a pentagon as graphs representing two 'being a neighbor' relations in the same set of five people.

Yes. Maybe it's right. It is even simpler than what I imagined.

Please see a note I added to the answer.
